# How does the voltage affect current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

The way I see it, volts are ways of measuring the electric potential of an electron in a circuit (I'm assuming from one end of the battery to the other but i could be wrong). So 1 coulomb of charge would have 8 joules of energy on the negative side of the battery and none on the positive side if it were an 8 volt battery.

If this is correct, how would volts affect the current (assuming the resistance is constant)? As in, do volts help "push" charge through a circuit? Are they both the potential energy of a coulomb and the "push" of the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As in, do volts help "push" charge through a circuit?

In a resistive circuit or through a resistor circuit element, yes. But be aware that not everything behaves like a resistor. For example, a DC voltage won’t push current through a capacitor regardless of its strength (up to dielectric breakdown, of course)

> Are they both the potential energy of a coulomb and the "push" of the current?

For a resistor this is approximately correct, except that it is the change in voltage rather than the voltage itself. Or in other words, as long as you are thinking of voltage as a difference between two points instead of an absolute number at each point.